# Is the log4net 1.2.11 NuGet package signed with the old 1.2.10 key?

Tags: log4net, nuget

I ran into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743992/how-do-i-work-around-log4net-keeping-changing-publickeytoken), and I was wondering if the [package on nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/2.0.0) was signed with the old key, or the new unsigned version?

I can't tell from the nuget portal.

Also, if it is indeed **not** the signed "oldkey" version, is there a way to use nuget to **get** that version?

Comment: You can use **sn -T log4net.dll** to display the key used (if any). But I would suspect that it would be signed with the new key. Not sure about your second part of the question.

Comment: Thanks @sgmoore, I was hoping there might be another package on nuget that I just can't find that has log4net signed with the old key.