# Annoying log4net assemly reference issue in vs 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, log4net

Getting following **build** error.

> Error 15  Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'log4net, Version=1.2.**11**.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=**669e0ddf0bb1aa2a**' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

I dont quite get whats going on.
I tried using GUI for references, it didn't help. Spent 1.5 hours on this already and issue is still present.

I go directly to project file now and the only reference to log4net there is the following:

> ```
> <Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
>   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
>   <HintPath>..\..\ExternalDlls\.NET 4.0\log4net.dll</HintPath>
> </Reference>
> ```

I still get this error. Why does it even mention V1.2.**11**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I checked all relevant log4net questions here. Looks like something special, although a lot of issues with referencing this log4net clearly exist.

Comment: Why don't you force your .net application to load Version=1.2.12.0 ? You can change web.config / app.config. More info here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx

Comment: Some info is given here as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743992/how-do-i-work-around-log4net-keeping-changing-publickeytoken and I think that guy has similar problem to yours.

Comment: try to install Log4net via Package manager https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net

Comment: Damith, while that indeed could actually fix things magically I would prefer to figure out what exactly is going on here, cause I dont like to feel stupid. I got a proj file that doens't refernece 1.2.11 . When I build project it throws error about it. I want to know what is up..

Comment: This sounds curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158928/referencing-2-differents-versions-of-log4net-in-the-same-solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay got build working finally.

I went through all other projects and did **Resharper - Remove unused references** action.

After it was done, project started to build.

Comment: Yeah. clearly related to issue described in question!.. don't you just love VS sometimes.

Comment: Do you use crystal reports by any chance?

I am getting the same issue as VS 2012 is adding reference path to another log4net.dll used by crystal reports causing the error. Its adding when I edit a report.

If I remove reference path, error goes away. Unfortunately I have to do it every time I edit a crystal report.

PS: I am using NuGet to maintain log4net in all projects.

Comment: Why would anyone want to use log4net in .NET apps when the System.Diagnostics Trace Class is so much simpler and better?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check what version actually exists in the Path **....\ExternalDlls.NET 4.0\log4net.dll** mentioned and see what version is present in **GAC**.

Remove the version in GAC, remove the below reference the from project file and add it again from the **ExternalDlls** folder

```
<Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\ExternalDlls\.NET 4.0\log4net.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: While I like GAC idea cause thats something external to proj file, I never put log4net there and it isn't there in fact after I checked: C:\Windows\system32>gacutil /l log4net
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.17929
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:

Number of items = 0 Please correct my command if its wrong.

Comment: Yes version exists. I got 15 projects in solution each referencing it just fine, just one project misbehaves for some reason.

Comment: I am sorry I am not aware of the command, but you can open it `C:\Windows\assembly` and you can see manually into the list of assemblies installed in `GAC`

Comment: Yep ty for easy shortcut. Not there sadly. Command works too.

Comment: Can you check the bin folder of your project for log4net project and see what version it is? It should be the same as `ExternalDlls`version. If not try to find the source of the other dll and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a nuget package that is referencing log4net make sure your nuspec file is specifying the correct version of log4net (this is the problem I ran into after log4net released the new build).  And make sure that if you don't want the latest version of log4net you encapsulate your version with "[" and "]" so that it doesn't get the latest.  See this.. http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Specifying_Version_Ranges_in_.nuspec_Files

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this issue today. To solve this problem I deleted log4net.dll file reference from Bin Folder through visual studio. and rebuild the website. 
It automatically picks up log4net dll. This solved problem. Reason for this issue was Reference bind through visual studio may not be upto date with the actual file version.