# How to assembly redirect log4net to newer version

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution, assembly-binding-redirect

I just upgraded log4net in my project and am having some assembly binding issues because a component relies on an older version of log4net.

The version expected by the component is

```
log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821
```

The version I have is

```
log4net, Version=1.2.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a
```

How do I cause this binding to resolve properly (there is only one api difference and it should not matter for this component).

I have tried adding the following to my web.config but it does not work.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="1b44e1d426115821" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.10.0" newVersion="1.2.12.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to perform a binding redirect to an assembly with a different public key.

1. You'll need to download the version of log4net v1.2.12.0 that is signed with the old key (http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/apache//logging/log4net/binaries/log4net-1.2.12-bin-oldkey.zip)
2. Then update your code, replacing references to:

   `log4net, Version=1.2.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a`

   with

   `log4net, Version=1.2.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821`

On a related note: you can put a version range in the redirect `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.11.0"`, for added flexibility.

Comment: I've also [found a way to include both assemblies side by side.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158928/referencing-2-differents-versions-of-log4net-in-the-same-solution/3163050#3163050) [Ugh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743992/how-do-i-work-around-log4net-keeping-changing-publickeytoken)